# How to calculate week number corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application I have to get current week number of this year. And display current the week date. After I change the week number date also update.

```
local current_Year = tonumber(os.date("%Y",os.time(t)))
datastring = current_Year.."-01-01T00:00:00"
start_datevalue = makeTimeStamp(datastring)
diffday = os.time()-start_datevalue
week_txt.text=math.floor((diffday/86400)/7)+1
```

This code returns the current week. But how can I get the first date on this week and when in change week number how retrieve first date of that week number.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the modulo command which you could use to return the day of the week with.

It would be something like `weekday_txt.text=(diffday/86400)%7`.

You could also use  `os.date` and `os.time`. [Here is some documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)  on those functions.